# MySQL - Order query and display one random row at the top

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like:

```
ID  |  TICKET PRICE  |  VIP
----------------------------
 1  |     $45.00     |  1
 2  |     $40.00     |  1
 3  |     $20.00     |  0
 4  |     $65.00     |  0
 5  |     $45.00     |  1
```

I need to query this table to order all rows by Price, but always show one random row which has a VIP=1 at the top. So for example, the query should return:

```
ID  |  TICKET PRICE  |  VIP
----------------------------
2  |     $40.00     |  1 
3  |     $20.00     |  0    
1  |     $45.00     |  1
5  |     $45.00     |  1     
4  |     $65.00     |  0
```

And when you refresh the page, row ID 5 may then become the first row, because it has a VIP=1.

I currently have my query looking like:

```
(SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE VIP=1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE VIP=0 ORDER BY ticket_price ASC)
```

This issue with this is that it will only display one VIP row. How would I query this data properly?

Comment: I think i am misunderstanding why cant you just remove VIP=0 if you want all the VIP and the random ticket

Comment: @silverpenguin then the VIP ticket row at the top will repeat twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `order by`.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from tickets t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by vip desc, rand()
     ) t
order by (seqnum = 1) desc, price asc;
```

This uses the subquery to identify the one row to keep at the top.  Then it uses this information for ordering in the outer query.

If your rows have a unique identifier, you could also do:

```
select t.*
from tickets t cross join
     (select id from tickets where vip = 1 order by rand() limit 1) as t1
order by (t.id = t1.id) desc, price asc;
```