# MySQL Query 2 records at top followed by the rest

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck with the following problem.

I have a website with for example supermarket shopping items. People can search the website for items.
Now I want on the search result page at the top 2 items to be displayed that I have selected to be on offer. There can be lots more items on offer.

So for example, someone would search for shampoo, the query would display all the shampoo items in the database table but I want just 2 shampoo offer items at the top of the query. There could be 2 or more shampoo offers in the database table, then the other would just not be shown.

Example with names :

Table:

```
    id      name      C      D   
----------------------------------
    1       Jack      1      1       
    2       Joe       1      1 
    3       Dave      3      0 
    4       Sue       1      0
    5       Mike      1      1
    6       Steve     4      0
    7       David     1      0 
    8       Susan     4      1 
    9       Marc      1      1
    10      Ronald    4      1
    11      Michael   4      1
```

EXAMPLE 1

Query :
WHERE C = 1 AND D = 1 (But only maximum of 2 'D' records, these 2 'D' records show at the top of the result)

Desired Query Result :

```
    id      name      C      D   
----------------------------------
    1       Jack      1      1       
    2       Joe       1      1  
    4       Sue       1      0
    7       David     1      0
```

EXAMPLE 2

Query :
WHERE C = 4 AND D = 1 (But only maximum of 2 'D' records, these 2 'D' records show at the top of the result)

Desired Query Result :

```
    id      name      C      D   
----------------------------------
    8       Susan     4      1 
    10      Ronald    4      1      
    6       Steve     4      0
```

I hope this explains my goal what I'm trying to achieve.

Many thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969038/mysql-order-query-and-display-one-random-row-at-the-top/34969779#34969779.

Comment: I had to leave this as a comment not related to the question. @MyBrainHurts your nickname is hilarious, and with the picture along with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's two queries that you can combine with UNION ALL:

```
select * from mytable where c = 1 and d = 1 limit 2
union all
select * from mytable where c = 1 and d = 0
order by d desc;
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to have the two rows chosen randomly, then order by RAND(). (Without an ORDER BY the rows are chosen arbitrarily, which means it's not guaranteed to get the same two rows picked again when re-running the query ‐ but it's quite likely.) As we need an ORDER BY for a partial query (the first query in the complete union-alled query), we must use parentheses, because otherwise only one ORDER BY would be allowed, namely for the complete query at the query's end.

```
(select * from mytable where c = 1 and d = 1 order by rand() limit 2)
union all
(select * from mytable where c = 1 and d = 0)
order by d desc;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed53f6/3.

Comment: I have just tried this and this works exactly how I wanted it work. Such an easy query. Thank you so much for your response and help!

Comment: What if I would like to have the results of the first query randomized?

select * from mytable where c = 1 and d = 1 order by Rand() limit 2
does not work.

Comment: *Whenever* a query doesn't work for you, don't say "it does not work". Say *what* does not work. Are you getting an error, too few or too many rows, always the same rows, ...? I've updated my answer to show the use of `ORDER BY RAND()` in the query.

Comment: That "order by rand()" is a real cool trick I hadn't thought about yet. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Thorsten! Also thank you for reminding me to be clear. WIll for sure think of that next. Many thanks again!